# discord.py: Fetch an Asset object via a cdn.discordapp URL

Tags: python, discord.py

Tl;dr Is there a way to fetch an Asset object from a https:// cdn.discordapp URL, such as 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/235088799074484224/9b29bfc497a70b6cc85bb2087936f8fd.webp?size=1024'?

...I ask as I have built one command which will send a discord.Member.avatar_url of a given member as a message in the channel it was called in. The content of that message is just the cdn URL, as above.

I have a further command which will manipulate the image in a referenced message. As part of that, I'd like to obtain the image as a bytes object - this is simple when working with attachments, and even with images on other URLs, but I get a HTTP 403 forbidden error whenever I use urllib.request.urlretrieve on a discord cdn URL. Here's an example snippet:

```
url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/235088799074484224/9b29bfc497a70b6cc85bb2087936f8fd.webp?size=1024"
filename = url.split("/")[-1]
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Which raises

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

So I'm looking for another way to retrieve an image from a discord cdn url. discord.Asset seemed like the most sensible class to try and accomplish this with but I can't see how to instantiate an object of it starting with just a discord cdn url. Is there a way to do this? Or is there a better way to fetch a cdn.discordapp image (from the url) as bytes?

Edit: I've realised that you can also get the proxy URL by checking discord.Embed.thumbnail.proxy_url of a given message, but I get 403 forbidden when trying to download from there too.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same problem, you can fake a browser visit by providing a User-Agent header:

```
    urllib.request.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36')]
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "test.jpg")
```